# Dynamic links using PHP and MySQL in a loop

Tags: php, mysql, loops, hyperlink

I'm learning PHP and MySQL for a self-project and apparently I got stuck. The site I am trying to make includes submitting forms and reviewing them. I've managed to create a loop in order to display all the forms that have been submitted and are not yet processed (therefore, prone to a review), and each form has its own link that redirects to the data the said form includes.

```
    $query = mysqli_query ( $conn, "SELECT * FROM members WHERE username = '$myrealusername' LIMIT 1" );
    $result = $query->fetch_assoc ();
    $id = $result ['id'];
    echo 'Welcome ' . $id . '. <br>';

    $quer = mysqli_query ( $conn, "select count(*) as total from carforms where aboveid='$id' and processed='0'" );
    $data = $quer->fetch_assoc ();
    $total = $data ['total'];
    $quer = mysqli_query ( $conn, "select fullname as CurrentName, formid as CurrentForm from carforms where aboveid='$id' and processed='0'" );
    for ($x=1; $x<=$total; $x++) {
        $data = $quer->fetch_assoc ();
        $forms = $data ['CurrentName'];
        $forma = $data ['CurrentForm'];
    echo  'Form No.'. $forma .' by: ' .$forms .'<a href="reviewform.php">Click here to review</a>.<br>'; 
    }
    ?>
```

and this is what it shows:

```
 Welcome 2. 
Form No.1 by: John Miller Click here to review.
Form No.2 by: John Miller Click here to review.
Form No.3 by: Mike Tywell Click here to review.
Form No.4 by: John Miller Click here to review.
Form No.5 by: Eric Paton Click here to review.
```

The problem is, that I have no idea how to pass different data to every link that is shown from the MySQL carform table that also includes data such as car type, car colour etc. and is different for each person.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add it as a query string e.g

```
  echo  'Form No.'. $forma .' by: ' .$forms .'<a href="reviewform.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Click here to review</a>.<br>';
```

fyi you can make this a lot simpler

```
 $query = mysqli_query ( $conn, "SELECT * FROM members WHERE username = '$myrealusername' LIMIT 1" );
    $result = $query->fetch_assoc ();
    $id = $result ['id'];
    echo 'Welcome ' . $id . '. <br>';

    $quer = mysqli_query ( $conn, "select id,fullname as CurrentName, formid as CurrentForm from carforms where aboveid='$id' and processed='0'" );
    while($data= mysqli_fetch_array($quer)) {

        $forms = $data ['CurrentName'];
        $forma = $data ['CurrentForm'];
    echo  'Form No.'. $forma .' by: ' .$forms .'<a href="reviewform.php?id='.$data['id'].'">Click here to review</a>.<br>'; 
    }
    ?>
```

Or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to add a parameter to the anchor

```
for ($x=1; $x<=$total; $x++) {
    $data = $quer->fetch_assoc ();
    $forms = $data ['CurrentName'];
    $forma = $data ['CurrentForm'];
    echo  "Form No. $forma by: $forms <a href='reviewform.php?formid=$forma'>Click here to review</a><br>"; 
}
```

In `reviewform.php` you will then be able to use the `$_GET` array to see what value was passed in the `formid` parameter

```
<?php
if ( isset($_GET['formid'] ) {
     // we have a parameter passed
```

You can add more than one parameter to the anchor like this

```
echo  "Form No. $forma by: $forms <a href='reviewform.php?formid=$forma&user=$id'>Click here to review</a><br>";
```